# why is the name callback for the callback function?

Tags: c, function, callback

please don't care or go strict on correcting the syntax. The point more important is why is the name callback for the callback function?

for example:-

```
function drive(int x, int y);
function breaker(int x, int y, callbackFunction);
int function main(){
    drive(23,24); // why is this called a "call to a function"?
    breaker(23,45,drive); // why "drive" here is called a callback and why not "call to function" like other function.
}

function drive(int x, int y){
   printf("%d%d",x,y);
}

function breaker(int x, int y, callbackFunction){
  callbackFunction(x,y);
}
```

The point here is not the accuracy of syntax. The point is i am calling the "drive" in main method and that is called as "calling the function" and when i pass the "drive" function as an argument to other function in "breaker" the "drive" is called as callback but why? any call to function have to refer to function and should execute it but why the difference in names?

Comment: Well, because you have to make a call first, to set it up, before it can call back.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Comment: Every function does the call back may be call back function the call has to be set up first. I don't know but i feel there must be some reason why it is called callback?

Answer (score 4):

```
breaker(23,45,drive); // why "drive" here is called a callback and why not "call to function" like other function.
```

This does not call `drive()`. This is a call to `breaker` with the address of the function `drive` as a parameter. The abscence of parenthesis denotes that we are not calling drive, we are passing the address of the function as a parameter.

The purpose of doing so is so that `breaker()` can call `drive()` as many times at it needs.

**Edit:**

The name callback is because the functions you are calling is calling your function back. This is more evident when the function with a callback parameter is provided by someone else.

Take the `qsort` function for instance. `qsort` is a standard C function that takes a comparator callback function and an array to sort. You call `qsort()` and `qsort()` calls your comparator whenever it needs to compare two elements in the array. So a standard C function **calls back** to your code.

Comment: It's even valid to write it as `breaker(23, 45, &drive);`. I don't do that myself, but it might help illustrate that `drive` in this expression is *evaluated* to an address, just as with `&drive`, but it's not being called.

Comment: I do agree with u. My intention is not to say drive gets called. As u said that is a call to breaker but what i am asking is why the "drive" is called as clalback function when every function call does the callback? This is the point that i was looking into.

Comment: `drive` is called a callback function only when it is passed **by address** as a parameter to another function.

Comment: Yes i do agree on ur last comment. My question is even if there is a function call inside the function that u are calling. For example inside the main method there is a call for "drive" as the first statement. So even in this case the call to "drive" does the callback to its function definition so only when a function is passed as parameter to another method, why is it called a callback?

Comment: A function is called a callback function only when it is passed as a parameter to another method. In your `main`, the line `drive(23, 24);` is a normal call, so for that purpose `drive`is not considered a callback funtion. When `drive`is passed as a parameter to `breaker`, `drive` is a callback function.

Comment: Exactly that is what i am saying why is it called cllaback when the function is passed as an argument to another function. I do understand that this process is named callback but why the name callback why not just a call or some other name?

Answer (score 0):

```
breaker(23,45,drive);
```

this will replace callbackFunction with drive

```
function breaker(int x, int y, drive){
   drive(x,y);
}
```